# Parsing a string into date at the time the DST change happened

Tags: python, datetime, time, dst, pytz

In western Europe, `2019-10-27 02:30:00` could be "two" time-events:

- 02:30 am before DST change at 03:00
- 03:30 am, which became (after DST change at 03:00) 02:30 am

**How does `datetime` parser and `pytz` deal with the fact parsing this date could result into two different time-events?**

```
import datetime, pytz
d = datetime.datetime.strptime("2019-10-27 02:30:00", '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
d = pytz.timezone('Europe/Paris').localize(d)
print(d, d.timestamp())
```

The answer is `2019-10-27 02:30:00+01:00  1572139800.0`, **why not `2019-10-27 02:30:00+02:00`?** Both could have been possible.

---

Remark:

```
import datetime
print(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1572139800.0))  # 2019-10-27 02:30:00
print(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1572136200.0))  # 2019-10-27 02:30:00
```

(these two different UTC timestamps have the same datetime in Europe/Paris timezone indeed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The direction is determined by the `is_dst` argument of the `localize` method.

> is_dst is used to determine the correct timezone in the ambiguous
>   period at the end of daylight saving time.

In the example in the question, using `True` will give you +02:00; and `False` +01:00

> Use is_dst=None to raise an AmbiguousTimeError for ambiguous
>   times at the end of daylight saving time

If a datetime instance is naive (or don't include a timezone) using `localize` will apply a timezone assuming the supplied instance is in local time and apply the offset to the targetted timezone.

After using `localize` the datetime instance will no longer be naive and the two values will equal one another as they are technically the same time.

---

This question is highlighting one annoying behaviour of the `datetime` module, unless explicitly specified `datetime` instances are naive, this includes using `strptime` if your matching expression does not include a time offset.

By changing the example to include the optional timezone argument things become clearer:

```
import pytz
from datetime import datetime

tz = pytz.timezone("Europe/Paris")
print(datetime.fromtimestamp(1572139800.0, tz))  # 2019-10-27 02:30:00+01:00
print(datetime.fromtimestamp(1572136200.0, tz))  # 2019-10-27 02:30:00+02:00
```

With the timezone included, printing the resulting `datetime` instance will now include the offset to show the time is not actually the same.

I recommend using the `arrow` package for handling dates and times which always includes a timezone (defaults to the operating systems timezone).

**References**

- *Docs for localize method* - https://github.com/stub42/pytz/blob/master/src/pytz/tzinfo.py#L258

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This totally answers the remark indeed. About the first part of the question, how is chosen the answer of `datetime.datetime.strptime("2019-10-27 02:30:00", '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')`? It could be two datetimes in fact

Comment: Added notes on localise to cover that.

Comment: Heh defaulting to UK English. Fixed.